# templated function only available for certain types

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

Is there a way, that the following function is only visible, if a certain pre-set type is used?

```
//used, when T == double || T == float
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t K, size_t N>
void foo2d(){}
//used, when T == int || T == uint64
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t K, size_t N>
void foo3d(){}
```

how would i write them, and how would i call them?

This is not a duplicate, the other question does not answer this one, and even if, i cant even grasp the concept, how am i supposed to understand the other answers ... but thanks for the quick marking

Comment: well then tell me which answer is the right one

Comment: as if i could see this, if i ask a qeustion this basic

Comment: You can use `enable_if` and SFINAE on the return value to do this, for example: `template<typename T> std::enable_if_t< std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T > foo2d() {}`. This is only callable for `float`, `double`, and `long double`.

Comment: I agree it's not quite close enough to close as a dupe.

Comment: @metal Thank you, what would the equivalent be for int and uint64_t (basically whole numbers)?

Comment: @metal well, the duplicate basically came in as soon as i asked this question, and it is not like i didnt lokk at other questions beforehand

Comment: [`std::is_integral_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral), which includes some things you may not expect like `char` and `bool`. Otherwise, you can build your own with `std::is_same_v` and other things in `<type_traits>`.

Comment: @metal could you maybe write it as an answer, with proper code indentation, i am still struggling a bit with this kind of code

Comment: Perhaps you ask a new question with your specific problems demonstrated. That way I can reply in an answer box with formatting. I cannot do so here because the question is closed. (Note that someone has added more dupe questions that are closer matches.)

Comment: Thank you for the offer, i actually did, and already got the answer, i'll link it here, so you can see what the problem was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128521/what-are-the-syntax-and-semantics-of-c-templated-code