# What are the syntax and semantics of C++ templated code?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, enable-if

```
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t K, size_t N, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T> = 0>
void fastor2d(){//...}
```

I copied this line of code from cpp-reference(only the `std::enable_if` part, i do need `T` and all three of the `size_t`'s), because i would like to use this function only when floating_types are used on it ... it does not compile.

Could somebody explain to me, why, and what it even does? While i am at it, how do you call this function afterwards?

Every tutorial or question here on SO gets bombed with answers, and that is great, but to someone who does not understand jacks*** of what is happening, even those are not really helpful.(sry, if possibly slightly agitated or aggressive)

EDIT: i greatly appreciate all answers as of now, i realize that my wording might have been a bit off ... i understand what a template parameter is, and know the difference between runtime and compiletime etc, but i just cant get a good grasp of the syntax behind `std::enable_if`

EDIT2:

```
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t K, size_t N, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
void fastor2d(){
    Fastor::Tensor<T,M,K> A; A.randInt();
}
```

This is literally the only thing i need changed. Notice the random() part

```
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t K, size_t N, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>>
void fastor2d(){
    Fastor::Tensor<T,M,K> A; A.random();
}
```

Comment: This might be a good place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Explaining C++ template syntax and use in a SO answer is a bit much to ask, I think. Entire books have been written on that subject.

Comment: Yeah, i realize that ^^ but, it would be a good start, if i just understood this part(i do understand what "static"  template parameters do, say typename T and size_t and stuff)

Comment: You should get yourself some [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) that cover template programming in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to explain this as simple as possible not to go into the language details too much since you asked for it.

Template arguments are compile time arguments (they do not change during the run-time of your application). Function arguments are run-time and have a memory address.

Calling this function would look something like this:

```
fastor2d<Object, 1, 2, 3>();
```

In the <> brackets you see the compile-time arguments or more accurately the template parameters, and the function in this case takes 0 runtime arguments in the () brackets. The last compile time argument has a default argument which is used to check whether the function should compile at all (enable_if type). If you want to know more clearly what enable if does you should search for the term SFINAE, which is a template metaprogramming technique used to determine whether a function or class should exist or not.

Here is a short SFINAE example:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>>
void function(T arg)
{
}

function(0.3f);    //OK
function(0.0);     //OK double results in std::is_floating_point<double>::value == true
function("Hello"); //Does not exist (T is not floating point)
```

The reason the third function call fails, is because the function does not exist. This is because the enable if caused the function not to exist when the compile-time bool that is passed in as its' template argument is false.

```
std::is_floating_point<std::string>::value == false
```

Do note that a lot of people agree that the SFINAE syntax is horrible and that a lot of SFINAE code will not be necessary anymore with the introduction of concepts and constraints in C++ 20.

Comment: This works, but now i get the line, that if have code duplication, as i wanted one for float and one for int ... is there a quick way around that?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but it seems like you don't have enough of a basic understanding how generic programming works, I think you should look up basic template usage first before getting into enable if.

Comment: OP may also want to look into [if constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) in addition to SFINAE.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a top-down approach starting with you code snippet, I'll take a bottom-up approach to explain some important details about templates and what tools and techniques are involved.

---

At heart, templates are a tool that let you write C++ code that applies to a *range* of possible types, not strictly for a fixed type. In a statically-typed language, this is firstly a great tool for reusing code without sacrificing type safety, but in C++ in particular, templates are very powerful because they can be *specialized*.

Every template declaration begins with the keyword `template`, and a list of *type* or *non-type* (i.e *value*) parameters. Type parameters use the special keyword `typename` or `class`, and are used to let your code work over a range of types. Non-type parameters simply use the name of an existing type, and these let you apply your code to a range of *values* that are known at compile-time.

A very basic templated function might look like the following:

```
template<typename T> // declare a template accepting a single type T
void print(T t){ // print accepts a T and returns void
    std::cout << t; // we can't know what this means until the point where T is known
}
```

This lets us reuse code safely for a range of possible types, and we can use it as follows:

```
int i = 3;
double d = 3.14159;
std::string s = "Hello, world!";
print<int>(i);
print<double>(d);
print<std::string>(s);
```

The compiler is even smart enough to deduce the template parameter `T` for each of these, so you can safely get away with the following, functionally identical code:

```
print(i);
print(d);
print(s);
```

But suppose you want `print` to behave differently for one type. Suppose, for example, you have a custom `Point2D` class that needs special handling. You can do this with a *template specialization*:

```
template<> // this begins a (full) template specialization
void print<Point2D>(Point2D p){ // we are specializing the existing template print with T=Point2D
    std::cout << '(' << p.x << ',' << p.y << ')';
}
```

Now, anytime we use `print` with `T=Point2D`, the specialization is chosen. This is really useful, for example, if the generic template just doesn't make sense for one specific type.

```
std::string s = "hello";
Point2D p {0.5, 2.7};
print(s); // > hello
print(p); // > (0.5,2.7)
```

---

But what if we want to specialize a template for *many* types at once, based on a simple condition? This is where things become a little meta. First, let's try to express a condition in a way that lets them be used inside templates. This can be a little tricky because we need compile-time answers.

The condition here will be that `T` is a floating point number, which is true if `T=float` or `T=double` and false otherwise. This is actually fairly simple to achieve with template specialization alone.

```
// the default implementation of is_floating_point<T> has a static member that is always false
template<typename T>
struct is_floating_point {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

// the specialization is_floating_point<float> has a static member that is always true
template<>
struct is_floating_point<float> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

// the specialization is_floating_point<double> has a static member that is always true
template<>
struct is_floating_point<double> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
}
```

Now, we can query any type to see if it's a floating point number:

```
is_floating_point<std::string>::value == false;
is_floating_point<int>::value == false;
is_floating_point<float>::value == true;
is_floating_point<double>::value == true;
```

But how can we use this compile-time condition inside another template? How can we tell the compiler which template to choose when there are many possible template specializations to choose from?

This is achieved by taking advantage of a C++ rule called [SFINAE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/SFINAE), which in basic English, says, "when there are many possible template specializations to choose from, and the current one doesn't make sense*, just skip it and try the next one."

- There's a list of errors, when attempting to substitute template arguments into templated code, that cause the template to be ignored *without an immediate compiler error*. The list is a bit [long and complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

One possible way that a template doesn't make sense is if it tries to use a type that doesn't exist.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(typename T::nested_type x); // SFINAE error if T does not contain nested_type
```

This is the exact same trick that `std::enable_if` uses under the hood. `enable_if` is a template class accepting a type `T` and a `bool` condition, and it contains a nested type `type` equal to `T` *only when the condition is true*. This is also pretty easy to achieve:

```
template<bool condition, typename T>
struct enable_if {
    // no nested type!
};

template<typename T> // partial specialization for condition=true but any T
struct enable_if<true, T> {
    typedef T type; // only exists when condition=true
};
```

Now we have a helper that we can use in place of any type. If the condition we pass is true, then we can safely use the nested type. If the condition we pass is false, then *the template is no longer considered.*

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, void>::type // This is the return type!
numberFunction(T t){
    std::cout << "T is a floating point";
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_floating_point<T>::value, void>::type
numberFunction(T t){
    std::cout << "T is not a floating point";
}
```

I completely agree that `std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, void>::type` is a messy way to spell out a type. You can read it as "`void` if T is floating point, and otherwise stop and try the next overload"

---

Finally, to take apart your example:

```
// we are declaring a template
template<
    typename T, // that accepts some type T,
    size_t M,   // a size_t M,
    size_t K,   // a size_t K,
    size_t N,   // a size_t N,
    // and an unnamed non-type that only makes sense when T is a floating point
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T> = 0
>
void fastor2d(){//...}
```

Note the `= 0` at the end. That's simply a default value for the final template parameter, and it lets you get away with specifying `T`, `M`, `K`, and `N` but not the fifth parameter. The `enable_if` used here means that you can provide other templates called `fastor2d`, with their own sets of conditions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'll rewrite your function in a working form

```
template <typename T, size_t M, size_t K, size_t N,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int> = 0>              
void fastor2d() // ..........................................^^^  int, not T
 { }
```

The point is that I've changed the second template argument of `std::enable_if_t` form `T` to `int`.

I've also removed the `typename` before `std::enable_if_t` but isn't important: the `typename` is implicit in the `_t` at the end of `std::enable_if_t`, introduced from C++14. In C++11 the correct form is

```
// C++11 version
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int>::type = 0
// ^^^^^^^^            no _t                                     ^^^^^^
```

But why it works?

Start from the name: SFINAE.

Is a short form for "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error".

It's a C++ rule so that when you write some thing as

```
 template <int I, std::enable_if_t< I == 3, int> = 0>
 void foo ()
  { }
```

and `I` is `3`, the condition of `std::enable_if_t` is `true` so `std::enable_if_t< I == 3, int>` is substituted with `int` so `foo()` is enabled but when `I` isn't `3`, the condition of `std::enable_if_t` if `false` so `std::enable_if_t< I == 3, int>` is not substituted so `foo()` isn't enabled but this ins't an error (if, through overloading, there is another `foo()` function, enabled, that matches the call, obviously).

So where is the problem in your code?

The problem is that `std::enable_if_t` is substituted, when the first template parameter is `true`, with the second parameter.

So if you write

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T> = 0
```

and you call

```
fastor2d<float, 0u, 1u, 2u>();
```

the `std::is_floating_point<float>::value` (but you can also use the shorter form `std::is_floating_point_v<T>` (`_v` and not `::value`)) so the substitution take place and you get

```
float = 0
```

but, unfortunately, a template value (not type) parameter can't be of type floating point, so you get an error.

If you use `int` instead of `T`, the substitution give you

```
int = 0
```

and this is correct.

Another solution can be use the following form

```
typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>
```

as suggested by Andreas Loanjoe, because the substitution give you

```
typename = float
```

that is a valid syntax.

But this solution has the drawback that doesn't works when you want to write two alternative functions, as in the following example

```
// the following solution doesn't works

template <typename T, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t<true == std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int>>
void foo ()
 { }

template <typename T, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int>>
void foo ()
 { }
```

where works the solution based on the value

```
// the following works

template <typename T, 
          std::enable_if_t<true == std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int> = 0>
void foo ()
 { }

template <typename T, 
          std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int> = 0>
void foo ()
 { }
```

Comment: `typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>` this worked for me, but because i need this function twice, once for float and then for int, i would like to keep the name same but change the body of the function(as it is literally just one line that depends on the type of T) ... but the compiler tells me, that i now have code duplication ... is there a way around that, or do i need to rethink it (i'd rather not)...

Comment: @CleboSevic - is what I've explained in the last part of my anser: with `typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>` you have a collision between the two functions; with `std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int> = 0` the collision should disappear (strange but is a C++ rule)

Comment: Thank you, i now works, man, this really is complicated, especially for it being my first encounter with this sort of code

Comment: @CleboSevic - I know... it's complicated. But don't be discouraged: SFINAE is a very powerful tool.